# How to represent $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a basis in which Hadamard product in $\mathbb R^n$ is isomorphic to the matrix product, and on the matrix main diagonal all elements be equal to the mean value of the elements of the vector in $\mathbb R^n$?

For instance, in $2$-dimensional case, we have

$$ (a,b) \to \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{a+b}{2} & \dfrac{b-a}{2} \\ \dfrac{b-a}{2} & \dfrac{a+b}{2} \end{pmatrix} $$

What would be in the $n$-dimensional case?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am speaking about a basis in which all elements on the main diagonal of the matrices are equal.

Comment: You should specify if matrices are required to by n-by-n.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4381090/442

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes, square matrices

Comment: @Anixx I meant that you are looking for a map $R^n\to Mat(n,n)$. This is what is unclear from the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible for all $n$, but it is possible for infinitely many $n$. In particular, if there exists a [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) (an $n \times n$ matrix $H$ with $\pm 1$ entries satisfying $H^TH = nI$) of size $n$, then it follows that a suitable representation exists.

Indeed: suppose that $H$ is a Hadamard matrix of size $n$. The matrix $Q = H/\sqrt{n}$ is orthogonal. It follows that the map $f:v \mapsto Q\operatorname{diag}(v) Q^T$ is such that $f(v \odot w) = f(v)f(w)$. To see that the diagonal entries of $f(v)$ are equal to the average of $v$, let $q_1,\dots,q_n$ denote the columns of $Q$. Each vector $q_i$ has entries $\pm 1/\sqrt{n}$, which means that the diagonal entries of $q_iq_i^T$ are equal to $1/n$. It follows that the diagonal entries of
$$
f(v) = \pmatrix{q_1 & \cdots & q_n} \pmatrix{v_1 \\ &\ddots \\ &&v_n} \pmatrix{q_1^T\\ \vdots \\ q_n^T} = v_1\,q_1q_1^T + \cdots + v_n\  q_nq_n^T
$$
are equal to $(v_1 + \cdots + v_n)/n$.

---

The answer to the corresponding question over $\Bbb C$, on the other hand, is yes. In particular, if $U$ denotes the [unitary DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_unitary_DFT) and $U^*$ denotes its conjugate transpose, then the map defined by
$$
f(v) = U \operatorname{diag}(v) U^*
$$
takes vectors to [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) and has all the desired properties.

For the case of $n=2$, this turns out to be the map $(a,b)\to\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{a+b}{2} & \frac{b-a}{2} \\
 \frac{b-a}{2} & \frac{a+b}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$ that you mentioned, but for larger $n$ it maps some real vectors to matrices with (non-real) complex entries.

Comment: Well, a complex matrix always can be represented as a real matrix of order 2n.

Comment: @Anixx That's a good point. So indeed, whenever $n$ is even, you can get a suitable representation using "block-circulant" matrices, or using matrices of the form
$$
\pmatrix{A & -B\\ B & A},
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are circulant.

Comment: Well, one can do it with any $n$, not only even.

Comment: @Anixx I don't see how you can use this to get a suitable map from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^{3\times 3}$, for example

Comment: Take the complex matrix $M$ representing $\mathbb{R}^3$ Now in each cell replace $a+bi\to\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 -b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$ or just take matrix $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \Re(M) & \Im(M) \\
-\Im(M) & \Re(M) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 c & a & b \\
 b & c & a \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \Re(a) & \Im(a) & \Re(b) & \Im(b) & \Re(c) & \Im(c) \\
 -\Im(a) & \Re(a) & -\Im(b) & \Re(b) & -\Im(c) & \Re(c) \\
 \Re(c) & \Im(c) & \Re(a) & \Im(a) & \Re(b) & \Im(b) \\
 -\Im(c) & \Re(c) & -\Im(a) & \Re(a) & -\Im(b) & \Re(b) \\
 \Re(b) & \Im(b) & \Re(c) & \Im(c) & \Re(a) & \Im(a) \\
 -\Im(b) & \Re(b) & -\Im(c) & \Re(c) & -\Im(a) & \Re(a) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: or $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 c & a & b \\
 b & c & a \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \Re(a) & \Re(b) & \Re(c) & \Im(a) & \Im(b) & \Im(c) \\
 \Re(c) & \Re(a) & \Re(b) & \Im(c) & \Im(a) & \Im(b) \\
 \Re(b) & \Re(c) & \Re(a) & \Im(b) & \Im(c) & \Im(a) \\
 -\Im(a) & -\Im(b) & -\Im(c) & \Re(a) & \Re(b) & \Re(c) \\
 -\Im(c) & -\Im(a) & -\Im(b) & \Re(c) & \Re(a) & \Re(b) \\
 -\Im(b) & -\Im(c) & -\Im(a) & \Re(b) & \Re(c) & \Re(a) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: @Anixx This is a valid representation of $\Bbb R^n$ multiplication with ${(2n)\times (2n)}$ matrix multiplication.  I thought that you were specifically interested in representations of multiplication in $\Bbb R^n$ using $n \times n$ matrix multiplication

Comment: Now, I wonder, whether one can get the regularized value of a sequence or series using linear-algebraic means... I mean, regularized value is the same as mean value, if it exists, but in case the mean is going to infinity, it is not the case.

Comment: Interestingly, the original vector represents eigenvalues of the matrix representation, so the inverse operation is simple.

Comment: For reference, the following code in Mathemaica implements the both methods: `V := {1, 2, 3, 4};
n := Length[V];FourierMatrix[n] . DiagonalMatrix[V] . ConjugateTranspose[
    FourierMatrix[n]] // ExpandAll // FullSimplify // MatrixForm // Print; HadamardMatrix[n] . DiagonalMatrix[V] . ConjugateTranspose[
    HadamardMatrix[n]] // ExpandAll // FullSimplify // MatrixForm // Print;`

Comment: It seems, using `H(n):=PadLeft[Array[JacobiSymbol[#2-#1,n-1]&,{n,n}-1]-IdentityMatrix[n-1],{n,n},1]` instead of `HadamardMatrix[n]` will work for any order, no? Even for order 3?

Comment: @Anixx I don't know anything about the Jacobi Symbol, so I couldn't tell you. If $H(n)$ turns out to be a matrix with a constant diagonal and mutually orthogonal columns of the same length, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Is there an opposite operation, to represent matrix as a vector in $\mathbb C^n$?

Comment: I think, no, because matrix product is not commutative while Hadamard product is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Mathematica code implementation of the both methods by @BenGrossman:

```
V := {1, 2, 3, 4};
n := Length[V];
FourierMatrix[n] . DiagonalMatrix[V] . ConjugateTranspose[
        FourierMatrix[n]] // FullSimplify // ExpandAll // MatrixForm // Print; 
HadamardMatrix[n] . DiagonalMatrix[V] . ConjugateTranspose[
        HadamardMatrix[n]] // FullSimplify // ExpandAll // MatrixForm // Print;
```

For $n=2$, the both methods return the same result, the one from the question.

**UPDATE**

Defining

```
H[n]:=PadLeft[Array[JacobiSymbol[#2 - #1, n - 1] &, {n, n} - 1] - 
  IdentityMatrix[n - 1], {n, n}, 1]/Sqrt[n]
```

and inserting `H(n)` intead of `HadamardMatrix(n)` will make the second formula to work with any `n` which is a multiple of $4$ and a prime plus one at the same time, and not only with powers of $2$.