# How to represent a matrix as a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4484821/2513) gives solution on how to represent a vector as a matrix, but what is the opposite operation? Is it possible to represent a matrix as a vector in such a way that matrix product to be isomorphic to Hadamard (element-wise) product of the vectors?

Answer (score 1):

No, since the matrix product is non-commutative, and the vector dot product is.

Comment: They asked about the Hadamard product, rather than the dot product, but this is also commutative, so your point stands.

Comment: Oh. I guess the Hadamard product is different from the dot product in $\mathbb{C}^n$ yeah.